# Best way to convert a large selection of database being read as ResultSet to a JSON string using Streams and Gson?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, gson

I have a large result from DB object that I want to convert to a a json string and pass as a message to pubsub. I am new to Java 8 streams and I can not figure out what is the best way to use that. I usually use
 `new Gson().toJson(myArrayList.toArray(), T[].class)` but I want to avoid storing large objects in the memory so avoid making the ArrayList as one of the answers suggested.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Answer (score 1):

Given that your arraylist is already a giant object, what you're attempting to avoid is, at worst, a constant factor of 2x (that you need 2x the memory you already need now). In other words, there is no point in trying to stream your JSON here.

If you have a stream of objects which are being read one at a time from someplace (say, you're iterating through a DB resultset and converting each 'row' into an object e.g. with JOOQ or JDBI or hibernate, and you want to send these out via JSON), then what you want makes plenty of sense.

In other words, the advice is: Don't bother, you won't gain anything useful. If you want to spend time to make this code less memory intensive, then go back to the code that ends up making a gigantic arraylist and change *that* to make a stream (lower-case s. Could be an actual java.util.stream.Stream, but more likely an iterator or just a different code structure).

Only then worry about the JSON part. Once you've done that, investigate [this wiki page on streaming GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).